# how to declare a list element as REGEX

Tags: python

I want to declare a regex as r'tata.xnl.*-dev.1.0' in the list element and it should match `tata.xnl.1.0-dev.1.0`,how to solve this problem?.

```
productline = '8.H.5'
pl_component_dict = {'8.H.5': [r'tata.xnl.*-dev.1.0','tan.xnl.1.0-dev.1.0'],
                     '8.H.7':['']
                     }
component_branch = "tata.xnl.1.0-dev.1.0"
if component_branch in pl_component_dict[productline] :
    print "PASS"
else:
    print "ERROR:Gerrit on incorrect component"
```

Error:-

```
ERROR:Gerrit on incorrect component
```

Comment: What `tata.xnl.1.0-dev.1.0` should it match? Do you expect the regex to match or the `component_branch in..` to match. If it's the regex, how do you expect it to match anything if you don't _use_ the pattern with one of the `re` methods?

Answer (score 0):

Make the dictionary value(s) compiled `re` that can match your string:

```
import re

productline = '8.H.5'

pattern = re.compile(r'tata.xnl.\d\.\d-dev.1.0')
pl_component_dict = {'8.H.5': pattern}

component_branch = "tata.xnl.1.0-dev.1.0"

if pl_component_dict[productline].match(component_branch):
    print "PASS"
else:
    print "ERROR:Gerrit on incorrect component"
```

Answer (score 0):

Prepending `r` to a string does not make it a regular expression - it makes it a [raw string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-in-python-and-what-are-raw-string-l).

You need to *compile* it into a regular expression using `re.compile()`.

```
import re
...
for component in pl_component_dict[productline]:
    if re.compile(component).match(component_branch):
        print "PASS"
        break
else: # note that this becomes a for-else, not an if-else clause
    print "ERROR:Gerrit on incorrect component"
```

This for-else loop takes care of the event where you have a list in `pl_component_dict[productline]` as you do in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search):

```
import re

class ReList:
    def __init__(self, thinglist):
        self.list = thinglist
    def contains(self, thing):
        re_list = map( lambda x: re.search( x, thing) , self.list)
        if any( re_list):
            return True
        else:
            return False

my_relist = ReList( ['thing0', 'thing[12]'] )

my_relist.contains( 'thing0')
# True
my_relist.contains( 'thing2')
# True
my_relist.contains( 'thing3')
# False
```

The `any` statement works because `re.search` either returns an [`re.MatchObject`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject) with a boolean value of True, or else it returns `None`.